# How do write a generic function that takes a datarow and fill an object's properties?

Tags: c#, .net, data-binding, reflection

I have some function like

```
private static UserInfo FillUserInfoFromDataRow(DataRow dr)
{

     UserInfo user = new UserInfo();

     user.UserID = (int) dr["UserID"];
     user.UserName = (int) dr["UserName"];
     user.ProjectID = (int) dr["ProjectID"];
     user.ClassID = (int) dr["ClassID"];
     ..............

     return user;
}
```

I'd like to write some generic function like
private static T FillEntityInfoFromDataRow(DataRow dr), that will treat analogous types ProjectInfo, JobInfo, etc.

I can get all columns names of the DataRow parameter, but I don't know how to get all the appropriate fields of the generic T type and how to do appropriate casting.
Is it some way to do this job?
Thanks!

Ilan.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Its better to make use of reflection there are no of example avaible on google to do this this.

Check the below example

```
namespace MyNamespace.Data
{
    class Converter
    {
        public static void Fill(object LogicObject, DataRow Row)
        {
            Dictionary<string, PropertyInfo> props = new Dictionary<string,PropertyInfo>();
            foreach (PropertyInfo p in LogicObject.GetType().GetProperties())
                props.Add(p.Name, p);
            foreach (DataColumn col in Row.Table.Columns)
            {
                string name = col.ColumnName;
                if (Row[name] != DBNull.Value && props.ContainsKey(name))
                {
                    object item = Row[name];
                    PropertyInfo p = props[name];
                    if (p.PropertyType != col.DataType)
                        item = Convert.ChangeType(item, p.PropertyType);
                    p.SetValue(LogicObject, item, null);
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Check the full blog post : http://kasey-jo.blogspot.com/2009/04/using-reflection-to-fill-business-layer.html

Comment: +1 - maybe with a generic overload just takes the 'DataRow' and creates the object itself?

Answer (score 2):

I use this, which is sort of like what you need:

**EDITED thanks to Heinzi**

```
    public virtual void LoadDataRow(DataRow drow, params string[] parameters)
    {
        this.LoadDataRow(drow);
        foreach (string property in parameters)
        {
            try
            {
                if (drow[property] != null)
                {
                    PropertyInfo pi = this.GetType().GetProperty(property);
                    if (pi != null && drow.Table.Columns.Contains(property))
                    {
                        pi.SetValue(this, drow[property], null);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch { throw; }
        }
    }
```

In your case though, you might want to loop through th eproperty collection of your object first, and try to load from your dataset, but th eabove code should get you started.

EDIT

Found this on MSDN:

```
System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[] p = MyObject.GetType.GetProperties();
foreach(System.Reflection.PropertyInfo prop in p)
{
  ....
}
```

Comment: +1 for the solution, -1 because "Errors should never pass silently".

Comment: @Heinzi, ha, good spot. In my case though, if I'm asking for, say "EmptyParameter", and it's not there, I don't care. But good point though. Shame on me....

Comment: This solution is very simple and great for really straightforward relations between property and a value from DataBase, but this is not always happens in real life. Anyway this could be as a base implementation of CreatFromDataRow() and any specific entity could override this behaviour

Comment: @Oxonhammer: I understand. Still, I recommend to replace the try-catch with a few `if` statments: [Type.GetProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kz0a8sxy.aspx) returns null if the property is not found, and for the datarow something like `drow.Table.Columns.Contains(property)` does the check. That makes sure that you don't accidentally drop *real* errors.

Comment: Thanks @sll. I actually use this inside my BaseBusinessObject, and missed out the this.LoadDataRow(drow); from this code. My Concrete class has a standard load method (they all do), but sometimes I have stored procs that return extra fields. So I use this to obatin those extra values. As in:

`object.Load(standardDR); // Standard load.
object.Load(enhancedDR, "NewField1", "NewField2"); // Enhanced load!
`

Answer (score 0):

Delegate this functionality to each specific class itself by declaring abstarct method in base class. 
BTW, I suggest to name this method like `CreateFromDataRow()`

```
abstract class InfoBase
{
    public abstract InfoBase CreateFromDataRow(DataRow dr);
}
```

OR

```
abstract class InfoBase<T>
{
    public abstract T CreateFromDataRow(DataRow dr);
}
```